# How to database migrate from Orchard 1.2 to Orchard 1.4.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I am using Orchard 1.2 for one of my web application and I am going to upgrade it to Orchard 1.4.1. I have done necessary code migration but..

Q1: How would I migrate existing database to newer version? If I run newer version with connecting existing (old 1.2 versioned) database then server error occurs like below

> "Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /http404error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya, I got the clue. There are a module named UpgradeTo14 in Orchard 1.4.1. This module is used to upgrade database to new orchard version.

For details information :
http://www.sarasota.me/blog/orchard-website-upgraded-to-1.4-autoroute-projector-module-and-new-fields

Comment: but the server error occurs because, it hits to AccessDenied method in AccountController of Orchard.Users with a returnUrl parameter which is not found and server error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Check the source package, there are always migration scripts.
But seem you'd have to migrate from 1.2 to 1.3, and only after 1.3 to 1.4.
But once again check the package, maybe there is migration script from 1.2 to 1.4.

Comment: Also make sure to go to /admin and run the migrate to 1.3 tool from there.

Comment: Your wellcome, if answer was useful pls don't forget to mark it.